# Admob Not Enough Space for Banner Ad

Tags: java, android, eclipse, admob, banner

I can not figure out how to fix this problem. I was getting error

> Not enough space to show ad. Needs 360x50 dp, but only has 350x582 dp
>   .

and this is my layout code:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:gravity="center"
android:padding="5dp"
android:orientation="vertical"
>

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:ems="10"
    android:inputType="textMultiLine"
    android:maxLines="4"
    android:textSize="20dp" />

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="5dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Copy" />

    <ImageView
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:paddingRight="10dp"
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:onClick="keyBoardClick"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/keyboard" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Share" />
</LinearLayout>

<GridView
    android:id="@+id/gridView1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:numColumns="8" >
</GridView>

 <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
     android:id="@+id/adView"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     ads:adSize="SMART_BANNER"
     ads:adUnitId="myAdMobID" >

</com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>
```

What is wrong there, because I have match_parent for width and wrap content for height on adView.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

AdMob may or may not complain about "having enough room" but it will not show up if there is padding in the parent view. You need to wrap the views you want to have padding in either another layout or add padding to that particular view directly.

Please remove the padding from the parent layout:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:gravity="center"
android:orientation="vertical"
>
```

Comment: Oh this was the problem. Thank you @Rassel for fixing my issue! :)

Answer (score 0):

You should use `wrap_content` both for width and height.

```
<com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
    android:id="@+id/adView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    ads:adSize="SMART_BANNER"
    ads:adUnitId="myAdMobID" >
```

Comment: I tried that and same problem with wrap_content on both.